# Stop derby server hanging onto the terminal window

Tags: terminal, derby

Im running derby server from the command line on ubuntu. Problem is when i start it, it stays running in the terminal window, so it print all its logs straight to terminal. When i close the terminal window, the server shuts down. Is there anyway i can start derby from the command line, and then be able to close the terminal without shutting down the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can suspend it with CTRL-z and run it in the background with `bg` and then `disown %1` (or substitute 1 with the job number shown between the brackets in the suspend message).

Example...

```
$ bundle exec script/rails s
[1]  + 14192 suspended  bundle exec script/rails s
$ bg
[1]  + 14192 continued  bundle exec script/rails s
$ disown %1
$ exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is to use your window manager. Set up an application menu item that starts the network server for you, with the various output redirected to files. Then start your server by choosing that menu item.